# need help to show caller information

Tags: android, call, toast

I am developing an app which will show the service prvider (like Vodaphone etc) information , of incoming call.
I accommplished it using the toast. with following code

```
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) 
                {
                        // TODO React to incoming call.

                        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                        {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),finder.find(incomingNumber), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }

                }
                };
                telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

the problem is Toast is visible for very little time. I want to make it visible till the user does not receive the call(i.e. till the phone is ringing, once recievd toast should disapper).

what should I do.

Can I use some other control like dialogbox etc.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the toast in handler thread like following:

onclick of call button try the following:

```
            Button call = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //call the user function to make call

        }
    });
```

and add this method in your class:

```
        private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),finder.find(incomingNumber), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }

};
```

and cancel your toast onclick of end button or once the user picks the call:

```
           Button end= (Button) findViewById(R.id.end);
    end.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //call the function to end the call if the other user dont receive

        }
    });
```

otherwise use as like your function:

```
     if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
                    {
                            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

                    }
```

Comment: sry friend couldn't get u, please elaborate, I am a beginner.

Comment: declare private Handler mHandler = new Handler;